# Scalacache delete from cache set up with memoizeF

Tags: scala, caching, memoization, caffeine-cache

I'm using CaffeineCache together with `memoizeF` to cache the result of an operation that takes a case class as an input, like this:

```
    case class Foo(id: UUID, bar: String)

    implicit val myCache: CaffeineCache[Foo] =
      buildCache(cacheConfig.size) //builds the CaffeineCache

    def cachedOperation(foo: Foo): Future[Foo] =
      memoizeF(cacheConfig.duration) {
        // do something with foo and return it
      }
```

Now, in some cases I need to explicitly delete a specific element from the cache.

I think I could use `myCache.doRemove(key)` but from what I see in the ScalaCache documentation, when using `memoizeF` the key will be generated *"from the class name, the name of the enclosing method, and the values of all of the method’s parameters"* and I don't think backwards-engineering `key` from that and using it with `doRemove` is a good idea.

Is there another way of removing a specific element from the cache, if it was inserted using `memoizeF`? Or perhaps, could I in some way tell `memoizeF` to use `id` from Foo as the key instead of generating it from the class name etc (I know for certain that `id`s will be unique for every Foo instance)?

Perhaps using `memoizeF` is not a good idea at all for this scenario and I should go back to inserting to the cache "manually"? Any input is appreciated. I've looked in the official documentation and googled around but with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cache[F[_], V]` trait has explicit `caching` method where you can specify key for cache: https://github.com/cb372/scalacache/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/scala/scalacache/CacheAlg.scala#L56

So you can do:

```
case class Foo(id: UUID, bar: String)

val myCache: CaffeineCache[Foo] = buildCache(cacheConfig.size) //builds the CaffeineCache

def cachedOperation(foo: Foo): Future[Foo] =
   myCache.caching(foo)(cacheConfig.duration) {
        // do something with foo and return it
   }

def removeCache(foo: Foo): Future[Unit] = myCache.remove(foo)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed! Just making a note here that `cachingF` can be used to replace `memoizeF`- I think I wasn't clear in my original post that the "do something with foo" returned a future.